# In Corda, which case we should sign transaction with account key rather than node key?

Tags: corda

I am learning Account concept which is released in Corda 4.3. The concept also allows node sign the transaction by using account key rather than node key. I look into few aspects and have still questions that:

- In which case we should sign transaction with account key rather than node key?
- What would be a crucial benefit to use account key signing over node key?
- The framework allows transaction between accounts in the same node to be signed with account key. Why should we do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about what's the crucial benefit of signing with an account key instead of a node key, it's what your state contract dictates.
For instance if you look at the `gold-trading` example:

1. The state has an attribute `owningAccount`:

```
data class LoanBook(val dealId: UUID, val valueInUSD: Long, 
                    val owningAccount: PublicKey? = null) : ContractState
```

2. The contract dictates that the `owningAccount` is a required signer for the `TRANSFER` command:

```
inputGold.owningAccount?.let {
    require(inputGold.owningAccount in command.signers) { 
    "The account sending the loan must be a required signer" }
}
```

3. Notice how the flow signs the transaction with the node's key (because the initiator of a flow is a required signer), and the `owningAccount`'s key (because the contract dictates that):

```
val locallySignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder, 
                        listOfNotNull(loanBook.state.data.owningAccount, 
                        ourIdentity.owningKey))
```